# WEF error 5004 on server 2019

Tags: windows, windows-event-log, windows-server-2019

Having a really annoying issue with WEF configured in push mode on server 2019.
It is a domain controller, appropriate permissions are set on the logs and correct URL over HTTP for the subscription server. I know this because it is configured with GPO and 2012R2 servers function properly.
The error message in the event log for the forwarding service is just “The subscription could not be created 5004”, earlier I got error messages stating “handle is invalid” but that seems to be gone now.

Comment: Have you tried this : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4047777/security-event-log-forwarding-fails-with-error-0x138c-and-5004 ?

Comment: Yes, the setting is applied in GPO and works on all other servers. And yes I have verified that the SD is correct...